# Unable to add constraints to a label object in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I'm unable to add constraints to a label object in Xcode 7, when I press the add constraints button I'm not able to edit them. I've tried to move the label, rename it I've tried everything.

Comment: You can edit them directly using the inspector. Select the label and go to the inspector that looks like a ruler. Then I suggest learning more about auto layout and how constraints work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the label you want to add constraints to is selected. If you have trouble selecting it in the view, try selecting its name on the left side. 
If all else fails, maybe try deleting the label and trying again with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To add a restraint, make sure that you have selected the label, and then press the square / triangle icons in brackets on the bottom bar of the Main.storyboard file.  Select the restraints you want to add, then press 'Add constraints'.